# Get text between 2 given symbols in a string

Tags: ruby

Consider the below string

`str = "hellow >world<"`

is it possible for me to strip out text which occurs between `>` and `<`
using any inbuilt functions? or do i have to write custom function to achieve this?

Comment: It's customary on Stack Overflow to show your work. We want to know you've actually tried to solve a problem before asking for help.

Comment: Ok. I will provide information about my tryouts in my questions in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your very basic example, the following will return `"world"`

```
str.match(/>(.+)</)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the match method and a Regex, e.g.

```
str.match(/\>(\w+)\</)[1]
```

Comment: The only issue with yours *(not that mine is perfect)* is it won't match non-word characters (ie. `"hellow >world-test<"`)

Comment: I know :). I only tried to show '.match' and Regex. Personally, I do not like '.+'. I would prefer '[a-zA-Z0-9 ... ]'.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with split:

```
str.split(/[<>]/)[1]
```

Comment: What is faster? The '.match' or the '.split' way? (If the string is longer)

Comment: Not sure! Regex is certainly more pliable, but I figured I'd offer the split solution as an alternative. Could benchmark it for speed.

Comment: Actually this is less correct, if that should matter. The regex especially looks for characters enclosed by `>` and `<`, while this will split on any `<` or `>`, which might be just fine, or not :)

Comment: That's a good point! Hard to know if it's usable or not without a more accurate source data sample!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *keep* only the words between the symbols:

```
str.scan(/>(.*?)</).flatten
```

Unlike the other solutions here, this handles the case where you want to extract multiple words.

If you want to *strip* the words and keep the rest:

```
str.gsub(/>.*?</,"")
```